# HTML/CSS: Making my layout more user-friendly with different screen resolutions

Tags: html, css

I've been coding the layout I'm working on right now using only percents (%) and edm. Even though I don't code with pixels, my layout looks messed up on my 1920x1080 computer. On my 1280x800 computer it looks fine. What else could I do to make my layout more user-friendly across different screen resolutions?

---

1920x1080:
http://a.pictureupload.us/18160038325106dbaecbca8.png

1280x800:
http://a.pictureupload.us/15860427595106dba43723e.png

---

**index.html:**

```
<div id="blog">
        <h2>Lorem Ipsum</h2>

</div>
<div id="blog-description">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam ut tortor
    nec turpis rutrum suscipit eget ut ligula. Curabitur sit amet velit odio,
    id commodo nisl. Morbi non metus risus. Pellentesque vulputate, nisi id
    interdum imperdiet, lectus erat scelerisque risus, sed viverra mi lorem
    a neque. Sed et erat tristique arcu laoreet eleifend. Fusce libero ipsum,
    rhoncus at porta eu, consectetur quis...</div>
<div class="readmore"> <a href="./blog/" title="Read more...">
    <img src="http://a.pictureupload.us/14850301725106d9f0cc927.jpg" /><div class="readtext">
    <p>Read more...</p></a>

</div>
</div>
<img src="http://a.pictureupload.us/4249066075106d9f3bfe03.jpg" class="blogimg" />
```

**style.css:**

```
 #blog {
    position: relative;
    left: 15%;
    top: 8.000em;
    width: 15.000em;
}
#blog-description {
    position: relative;
    top: 8.300em;
    width: 25.000em;
    left: 16%;
    font-family: District Pro Thin;
    font-size: 1.100em;
}
.blogimg {
    position: relative;
    float: right;
    top: -15px;
    right: 16%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    border: #000 thin solid;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0em 0em 0.375em #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0em 0em 0.375em #000;
    box-shadow: 0em 0em 0.375em #000;
    /* For IE 8 */
    -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000')";
    /* For IE 5.5 - 7 */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Shadow(Strength=6, Direction=0, Color='#000000');
}
.readmore {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    top: 140px;
    left: 44.5%;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
}
.readmore .readtext a {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: District Pro Thin;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    /* in conjunction with left property, decides the text position */
    left:10px;
}
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, and what I found is that it depends on the browser. Thumbing this question up because its quite a good one.

Comment: one way is to not use absolute positioning to create your layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing you could do is put everything in a wrapper div and set that to some percentage of the screen width. Not a perfect solution, but it does narrow up the screen space you have to fill - especially useful for low-content pages like your example.

```
<div id="wrap"> ... </div>

#wrap{
  width:80%;
  display:block;
  margin:auto;
}
```

[OOCSS](http://oocss.org/) has some basic [layouts](http://oocss.org/template.html) and [percentage based columns](http://oocss.org/grids_docs.html) that could also help.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at http://goldengridsystem.com/

It is a simple grid system that allows you to build responsive designs for all types of screens and devices.